# how do you make ajax data key dynamic in jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to make my inline edit to be dynamic so it will just depend on some data- attributes from my markup so here's the code for now:

```
$(".inline-edit").editable(
  function(value, settings) {
    var editableField = $(this);

    $.ajax({
          type: 'PUT',
          url: editableField.attr('data-href'),
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(html) {
            editableField.parents('.replaceable').replaceWith(html);
          },
          data: { 'regression_test_environment[name]' : value }
        });
        return(value);
  },
  {
    event: 'click',
    width: '80%',
    height: '20',
    submit : 'OK'
  }
)
```

i want the name in regression_test_environment[name] to be editableField.attr('data-column-name') but it always fails in compiling because it keeps taking the key as a string. I tried making a variable after the editable field variable assignment and building the string as a different variable but it doesn't want to evaluate the key as a function.

Is there a way to do this? or am i stuck in creating a separate .editable call for each of my editable fields?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
var name = editableField.data('column-name');
var values = { };
values['regression_test_environment[' + name + ']'] = value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: editableField.data('href'),
    dataType: 'html',
    data: values,
    success: function(html) {
        editableField.parents('.replaceable').replaceWith(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: is the data() method available in ie7? i had the impression that you needed attr("data-whichever") for it to be accessible in ie?

Comment: i did attributes but the general idea worked. thanks man. its weird i think i've tried this awhile ago but couldn't make it work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 20):

Better, less confusing answer:

```
var data = {};
data[thisField] = $(this).text();

$.ajax({
    data: data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best is to pass dynamic values by serializing it :

```
    var data = $('#formid').serialize(); // serialize all the data in the form 
    $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php', // php script to retern json encoded string
    data: data,  // serialized data to send on server
    ...
    });
```

Comment: This won't help if I am sending a single input that is either not in a form or one of many parts of a form